# Unable to see modules description correctly on Odoo12 - How to fix it?

Tags: dependencies, odoo, odoo-12

I am using Odoo 12 on a new installed system and I am unable to correctly see the modules description under "Apps".

I have manually installed dependencies on "requirements.txt" and I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Please refer to the following image:

https://ibb.co/XDmkx8k

I am almost sure it's related with some missing dependency???

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was something related with browser cache.
After cleaning it, everything is working fine.

Thank you anyway